# MSMTP : How can I set a from field?

Tags: msmtp

I have installed [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html), and it seems to be working OK:

```
echo "Hello" | mail -s "Testing SmSMTP" destination@gmail.com
```

The email arrives to destination, But the `From` field is a **ugly** email text like `johnsmithsales@hotmail.com` .
I mean: `johnsmithsales@hotmail.com` is **correct**, of course, but I would like the receiver to read some **more professional** `John Smith - Sales Department <johnsmithsales@hotmail.com>` , like it can be done on any other email client.

What is the **proper way** to achieve this with MSMTP?

**Further notes**:

- I am running **Ubuntu** v20.04 .
- I have installed the **packages** `msmtp msmtp-mta mailutils`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
$ printf "From: John Smith - Sales Department <johnsmithsales@hotmail.com>\nSubject: Testing MSMTP\nHello." | msmtp -v destination@gmail.com
```

Note that I used `| msmtp` instead of `| mail` . I am not sure if that is important, because, as long as you install the `msmtp-mta` package, `sendmail is linked to` msmtp``.

Note that you can enhance the destination field in the same manner, like:

```
$ printf "To: Mr. Destination Man <destination@gmail.com>\nFrom: John Smith - Sales Department <johnsmithsales@hotmail.com>\nSubject: Testing MSMTP\nHello." | msmtp -v destination@gmail.com
```

Extracted from the [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/msmtp).